# Please check if the sentence is correct

Tags: conditionals

I would have passed the exam if there was a computer and internet in my house in 70s.

Answer (score 1):

'I would have passed the exam if there had been a computer and internet in my house in 70s.'

Comment: And just to be pedantic 'the 70s'.